# Deleting an API triggered email

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

We have an email triggered via our API that I need to "turn off".

It's identified in the API by an ExactTarget emailID. I'm not a developer nor am I in IT/Tech but trying to find a solution for my client while I await a response from our internal IT folks.   I'm trying to find the path of least resistance of making this happen.

I understand that updating the interface would probably be the best course of action, but I'm under a tight time constraint and have limited company resources to get this done in the short term.

My questions are:

1. What would happen if the email is deleted in ET?
2. I'm assuming a failure message would occur (to both our side and the client side of the API) when the emailID can't be found, but would there be any other impact?
3. Is it just a failure notification for that call or would it interrupt the entire service (we have other emails and clients on the same API system)?
4. I don't want it to be a nuisance, and can consider making the interface updates later but need a quick, cheap solution in the interim.

Answer (score 1):

What would happen if the email is deleted in ET?

If you delete this email chances are that your email will still go out as ET saves an snap of your emails even if you delete them they can recover it for you. If you want to delete this triggered email simply log a ticket to ET support and they can remove it from the backend.

I'm assuming a failure message would occur (to both our side and the client side of the API) when the emailID can't be found, but would there be any other impact?

I don't believe there would be any other impact.

Is it just a failure notification for that call or would it interrupt the entire service (we have other emails and clients on the same API system)?

I am not sure about this and the next question

Comment: I'm glad you know what you're talking about.

Comment: Thank you! We're going to test next week. I'll share our results here so others can enjoy the knowledge. :)